# Scan and map website and log all links that have "particular-string" in them

Tags: web-crawler

Is there a tool that would scan a website and log all links that have a particular string in them?

I see [Teleport Pro](http://download.cnet.com/Teleport-Pro/3000-12512_4-10002660.html), but it seems like it does make a copy of the site, but I only need links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need some kind of offline browser in order to automatically traverse all of the links on the site.  I haven't used Teleport Pro but [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) is a free offline browser that's pretty powerful.  They provide [an example](http://www.httrack.com/html/scripting.html) of how you can traverse a site looking for a particular keyword.

Comment: I ended up writing my own scraper in C#... Not so feature-rich, but does the job